# how prevent host to find an alternate image

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I have a default image to be displayed in case there is no image available.

```
<img src="user_608.png" onerror="this.src='user_default.png';">
```

It was working perfectly on the previous host, unfortunately I changed to 1&1 and it does not work anymore :

in case the file "user_608.png" does not exist, the host (I think it is the host, but I not sure), finds an alternate image by a kind of matching (or file completion or something like this) and it returns "user_1608.png"  instead of "user_default.png".

It seems it returns the closest file name to user_608.png instead of triggering the onError event.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain how to prevent host from selecting an alternate image, though you should be able to set `src` of image having value of `"user_1608.png"` to `"user_default.png"` at `load` event of `window`

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var img = document.querySelector("img[src*='user_1608']");
  if (img.length) {
    img.src = "user_default.png";
  }
});
```